# Pandas pivot table Nested Sorting Part 2

Tags: sorting, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

Given this data frame and pivot table:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['x','y','z','x','y','z'],
                 'B':['one','one','one','two','two','two'],
                 'C':[7,5,3,4,1,6]})
df


    A   B       C
0   x   one     7
1   y   one     5
2   z   one     3
3   x   two     4
4   y   two     1
5   z   two     6

table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['A', 'B'],aggfunc=np.sum)

table
A  B  
x  one    7
   two    4
y  one    5
   two    1
z  one    3
   two    6
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

I want to sort the pivot table such that the values are sorted descendingly within 'C'.

Like this:

```
A  B  
x  one    7
   two    4
y  one    5
   two    1
z  two    6
   one    3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean descending within 'C'?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Question has been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
df.groupby(['A'])['B', 'C'].apply(lambda x: x.set_index('B').sort_values('C', ascending=0))
```

Comment: I'm laughing at how good this is, if that makes sense at all. Thanks!

Comment: @DanceParty2 No, it doesn't make sense and that makes me laugh too.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
In [12]: pd.pivot_table(df, index=['A', 'B'],aggfunc='sum').reset_index().sort_values(by=['A','C'], ascending=[1,0])
Out[12]:
   A    B  C
0  x  one  7
1  x  two  4
2  y  one  5
3  y  two  1
5  z  two  6
4  z  one  3
```